# Finding DirectX12 libraries with CMake and MinGW

Tags: c, cmake, directx-12

I am trying to use CMake to find DirectX 12 and link it against an executable. What I have so far works when compiling with MSVC, but fails when compiling with GCC:
`Could NOT find D3D12 (missing: D3D12_LIBRARIES)`.

I am using a slightly altered version of the [FindD3D12.cmake](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindD3D12.cmake):

```
# Find the win10 SDK path.
if ("$ENV{WIN10_SDK_PATH}$ENV{WIN10_SDK_VERSION}" STREQUAL "" )
        get_filename_component(WIN10_SDK_PATH "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0;InstallationFolder]" ABSOLUTE CACHE)
        get_filename_component(TEMP_WIN10_SDK_VERSION "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0;ProductVersion]" ABSOLUTE CACHE)
        get_filename_component(WIN10_SDK_VERSION ${TEMP_WIN10_SDK_VERSION} NAME)
elseif(TRUE)
        set (WIN10_SDK_PATH $ENV{WIN10_SDK_PATH})
        set (WIN10_SDK_VERSION $ENV{WIN10_SDK_VERSION})
endif ("$ENV{WIN10_SDK_PATH}$ENV{WIN10_SDK_VERSION}" STREQUAL "" )

# WIN10_SDK_PATH will be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
# WIN10_SDK_VERSION will be something like 10.0.14393 or 10.0.14393.0; we need the
# one that matches the directory name.

if (IS_DIRECTORY "${WIN10_SDK_PATH}/Include/${WIN10_SDK_VERSION}.0")
        set(WIN10_SDK_VERSION "${WIN10_SDK_VERSION}.0")
endif (IS_DIRECTORY "${WIN10_SDK_PATH}/Include/${WIN10_SDK_VERSION}.0")


# Find the d3d12 and dxgi include path, it will typically look something like this.
# C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\um\d3d12.h
# C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\shared\dxgi1_4.h
find_path(
        D3D12_INCLUDE_DIR    # Set variable D3D12_INCLUDE_DIR
        d3d12.h              # Find a path with d3d12.h
        HINTS "${WIN10_SDK_PATH}/Include/${WIN10_SDK_VERSION}/um"
        DOC "path to WIN10 SDK header files"
        HINTS
)

find_path(
        DXGI_INCLUDE_DIR    # Set variable DXGI_INCLUDE_DIR
        dxgi1_4.h           # Find a path with dxgi1_4.h
        HINTS "${WIN10_SDK_PATH}/Include/${WIN10_SDK_VERSION}/shared"
        DOC "path to WIN10 SDK header files"
        HINTS
)
set(D3D12_INCLUDE_DIRS ${D3D12_INCLUDE_DIR} ${DXGI_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Find D3D libraries
set(D3D12_LIB_NAMES d3d12.lib dxgi.lib d3dcompiler.lib dxguid.lib)

set(D3D12_LIBRARIES)
foreach (D3D12_LIB_NAME ${D3D12_LIB_NAMES})
        find_library(${D3D12_LIB_NAME}_LOC NAMES ${D3D12_LIB_NAME} HINTS ${D3D12_HINTS_PATH})
        set(D3D12_LIBRARIES ${D3D12_LIBRARIES} ${${D3D12_LIB_NAME}_LOC})
endforeach(D3D12_LIB_NAME)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set D3D12_FOUND to TRUE
# if all listed variables are TRUE
find_package_handle_standard_args(
        D3D12  DEFAULT_MSG
        D3D12_INCLUDE_DIRS D3D12_LIBRARIES
)

mark_as_advanced(D3D12_INCLUDE_DIRS D3D12_LIBRARIES)
```

And then linking it with: `target_link_libraries(<name> ${D3D12_LIBRARIES})`.

The `D3D12_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable is set to the correct value, the problem is only with the libraries.

Are the DirectX 12 libraries not compatible with GCC and CMake is smart enough to figure that out, or am I doing something wrong when trying to find them?

## Edit:

As the answer mentioned, the `FindD3D12.cmake` module is not needed. The DirectX libraries are system libraries when compiling on Windows, so doing `target_link_libraries(<name> PRIVATE d3d12.lib dxgi.lib d3dcompiler.lib dxguid.lib)` works.

Comment: "Are the DirectX 12 libraries not compatible with GCC and CMake is smart enough to figure that out" - CMake doesn't check internals of the library files it searches for. And if you explicitly specify extension, then CMake should return the file if it exists. It seems that you incorrectly specify parameters for `find_library` call. E.g. what is **actual** value for `D3D12_HINTS_PATH` variable which denotes HINTS for the search? Does this directory actually contains a files? You may print value of `D3D12_LIBRARIES` variable after the loop and find out which exact libraries are not found.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now. The hints were always empty, but as one of the answers mentioned, MSVC is aware of the libraries, so the ```find_library``` always worked. When using GCC, it couldn't find the files. Manually setting the hints to the library folder makes the ```find_libraries``` succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

======================================================

Windows:

DirectX is part of the Windows SDK.

If you have are compiling on Windows there is no way you aren't using the SDK to compile. Therefor don't worry about handling the include directories and whatnot.

Therefore you can treat the Directx libraries as regular system libraries and the following command will work. That's the magic of cmake.

So most of your cmake isn't really necessary. At least if you are using visual studio.
If you aren't using visual studio you might need to write up a toolchain (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html?highlight=cmake_cxx_compiler_id#cmake-toolchains-7)

```
# DX12 libraries
target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE
    d3d12.lib
    dxgi.lib
    dxguid.lib
)
```

======================================================

Linux:

Secondly DirectX12 will have linux support:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-heart-linux/

However I don't think it allows use of graphics functionality, just the compute functionality. But regardless assuming Microsoft didn't make it extremely painful the cmake should be roughly similar.

======================================================

Lastly if you wanna know what version of the SDK you are building against check out CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION

On windows setting this before the first project call sets the SDK version. Because that's what the SDK versions stand for. Versions of windows builds.

Also to be extra cautious add extra static_asserts in your codebase to make sure you are using a version of the SDK you intended you'll want to include "Windows.h" which you probably already have anyway. And then check for the compiler definitions that tell you what Version of the Windows OS you are compiling.

"When you use the Windows SDK, you can specify which versions of Windows your code can run on. The preprocessor macros WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT specify the minimum operating system version your code supports. Visual Studio and the Microsoft C++ compiler support targeting Windows 7 SP1 and later. Older toolsets include support for Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, Vista, and Windows Server 2008. Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows NT, and Windows 2000 are unsupported." - Microsoft Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-160)

Comment: This helped me figure out the problem, thank you. The only reason the ```find_library``` was working on MSVC was that it was looking for system libraries. When using GCC, setting the hints to the path of the library folder makes the find command work.
Also, thanks for the explanation, I removed the unnecessary CMake and it's a lot cleaner now. Being able to specify the version of the Windows SDK is also very helpful.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please post your simplified code, for future users in case they stumble on this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the DirectX 12 libraries not compatible with GCC

Every compiler has its own library format, cl uses `.lib` libraries and gcc uses `.a` and `.so` libraries. You can't just take cl's libraries (which is what is stored in the Windows SDK) and feed them to gcc.

Comment: The reason I thought it should work is that I'm also linking Vulkan, which is a ```.lib``` and it works on gcc. Maybe it's built differently?

Comment: Maybe you're linking the `.a` and you don't realize it? Vulkan is a cross-platform API and it provides gcc libraries as well. DX is not a cross-platform API, and as such there is very little incentive to even have those libraries. You can probably muddle through the COM API by hand if you really try, but I see very little reason not to just use VS if you want to use DX.

Comment: Printing the ```Vulkan_LIBRARIES``` variable shows the ```.lib``` even when compiling with gcc. I've read some newer versions of gcc can be compatible with ```.lib```, but you do have a point, while on Windows there is not really any reason not to use vs and DX is just gonna be cut from the build if on Linux, which is where I would use gcc.

Comment: Just a quick note: from what I see on my Win10 system there are also DLLs (the equivalent of the Shared Object (`.so`) files on Linux).